# Laravel 5.2, redis,node.js,socket.io Real time application with private channels?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, laravel-5

What is the best way to implement chat like application in Laravel 5.2 (Actually it is not a chat, it is working with api calls and send notifications to browser and mobile devices) using

Socketio

Redis

nodejs

and frontend js

(These are good technologies as I know, What ever is better than that is accept)

Pusher is fine but it is not free for large scale, Need to use private channels also.

Thanks,

Lanka